# IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid certificates:

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, grpc

I have a Springboot GRPC client which using a cert file to connect to another grpc server.

```
file = inputStreamToFile(MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("cert.pem"));
SslContext sslContext = GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(file).build();
ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).sslContext(sslContext).build();
```

The implementation works fine as expected in local springboot run via Intellij; tested the interaction with server, works as expected but when i run the application by "mvn clean install", I got error, how to fix this?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid certificates: cert.pem

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: found no certificates in input stream
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably your service cannot find or cannot access the cert file.
Check if the file path seems right. If it is an integration test that fails, then the file may not be accessible from the test.
For example when it is placed in the wrong resources folder and does not get copied to the location of the test resources, then you may get this error.